# Updated VirtualBox and now my vagrant up command gets stuck

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I recently was prompted by VirtualBox to upgrade to the latest version (VirtualBox 5.1).  I am running a vagrant box (rmff/laravel-homestead-32bit).  Everything was working fine when I used the "vagrant up" command before upgrading VirtualBox.

After upgrading however, my vagrant up gets stuck at SSH Auth method ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipjPT.jpg)).  I tried to downgrade my virtualbox to the same version when it was working but it still errors out.  Nothing in the GUI is sticking out to me.  Please note that I am a beginner.

Comment: do NOT spam with irrelevant tags

Comment: Pretty new to this stuff.  An irrelevant tag was not intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. `vagrant destroy`
2. Go to VirtualBox console and check if the virtual machine still exists for some reason

   1. power down if for some reason it's on
   2. Right click and remove the machine with all files
3. Remove `.vagrant` directory from your Vagrant project
4. `vagrant up`

Comment: `vagrant down` ? you mean `vagrant halt` or `destroy` - guess you mean `destroy` with the rest of the answer

Comment: Of course I meant `destroy `, but my fingers are not used to typing it as I have alias. ;-) Thanks.